# scalar multiple of Young symmetriser

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-algebras

The following is a lemma on Fulton and Harris' book -Representation theory,a first course (page 53):
**Lemma**: For all $x\in \mathbb{C}\mathfrak{S}_r$, $c_{\lambda}\cdot x\cdot c_{\lambda}= scalar \;multiple\; of \;c_{\lambda} $. In particualr, $c_{\lambda}\cdot c_{\lambda}=n_{\lambda}c_{\lambda}.$
In the Lemma, $c_{\lambda}$ denotes the Young symmetriser corresponding to one standard tableau on partition $\lambda$.

The authors give a clear formula for $n_{\lambda}$. My question is that how to deduce a general formula for the scalar multiple of $c_{\lambda}$ for general $x\in \mathfrak{S}_r$? Until now I have no good ideas, so could anyone give me some suggestions on this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Travis : Dear Travis , I understand the lemma in this way,   from the lemma, $c_{\lambda}xc_{\lambda}=n_{x}c_{\lambda}$, where $n_x$ is the scalar multiple depending on $x$. So my question is that how to get a formula for $n_x$.

Comment: Dear Travis, in the Lemma, they determine the scalar multiple $n_{\lambda}$, which, from my point of view, corresponds to  the special case $x=(1)$. In other words, when $x=(1)$, the authors have determined $n_{(1)}=n_{\lambda}$, but what if $n_{x}$ for $x\neq (1)$? Do we have $n_{x}=n_{\lambda}$ for any $x\in \mathfrak{S}_r$?

Comment: Ah, I understand the question now, I misread it, but I do not know the answer, nor do I know another good reference for Young symmetrizers.